# How to get Notice.txt for third party references in .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core project including bunch of third party libraries. I can get list of all third party references using below dotnet command

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet list solFullPath package --include-transitive
```

Now as next step, I would like to get `NOTICE.txt` file for all the third party packages.

Is there a way to download through command line option?

Comment: https://github.com/bugproof/DotnetThirdPartyNotices

Comment: https://github.com/pleonex/ThirdLicense